# Identity on ASP.NET Core(3.0) not functioning when using endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

When I use routes, Identity is functioning as expected.

```
    //Identity functions as expected:
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

However, when I use endpoints, user is stuck in LogIn view (any attempt to access Action methods decorated with [Authorize] are redirected to my LogIn veiw, even after SignInResult succeeds).

```
// Identity not functioning when using endpoints:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

The rest of the app works fine using endpoints, my issue is only with Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the app uses authentication/authorization features such as
>   `AuthorizePage` or `[Authorize]`, place the call to `UseAuthentication` and
>   `UseAuthorization`: after, `UseRouting` and `UseCors`, but before
>   `UseEndpoints`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  ...

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
  ...
}
```

Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure) for more details